# ObjectBox Transaction using Android TextWatcher

Tags: android, database, objectbox

I want to develop real time data search in million. I'm using Android EditText addTextChangedListener to watch text typing. How do I use [Objectbox Transaction](http://objectbox.io/documentation/transactions/) to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the relevance of the transaction aspect; I'd say you should look at [queries](http://objectbox.io/documentation/queries/), e.g.:

```
userBox.query().starsWith(User_.firstName, "Joe").build().find();
```

Comment: typing isn't responsive and app forced close. i also added AsyncTask, but still same, when deep search, app not responsive and finally closed

Comment: How many objects do you have stored? Does the text property contain English words?

Comment: a milion data. its like car police number and car detail also

Comment: `startsWith` does not work with indexes yet. We're working on that. You could do some tricks with indexing a long value containing the first characters. Is that something you would consider?

Comment: PS.: With a million entries, it won't make much sense to start with one character because there would still be too many entries to display. At how many chars would it make sense to display potential results?